# Google Map doesn't show

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show a simple map from GM Api, and for some reason, when html is loaded "map_canvas" div is set to be hidden.Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.45, -70.66667),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        });

</script> 
</head>
<body>
body test
<div id="map_canvas">map test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put the word "map test" to test visibility.
Any thoughts ??

Thanks

Comment: You may not want to paste your actual key here.

Comment: There is no reason not to post a browser key, (the types required for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3) it has to be public (server keys are different, they should be protected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a witdh and height  to the map container

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, this worked with the reordering of the script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the script before the `</body>`, and after the `div#map_canvas`.

In your code, when the script is called, the id "map_canvas" does not exist.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
body test
<div id="map_canvas">map test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.45, -70.66667),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        });

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

You need also to use your API key ("YOUR_KEY"), and call a function with a callback. For example, on my website:

```
<!-- ... -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
    var styleArray = [
        {
            featureType: "all",
            stylers: [
                { hue: "#3e4950" },
                { saturation: -80 }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymaps'), {
        center: {lat: 48.6949454, lng: 2.1856039},
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        // Apply the map style array to the map.
        styles: styleArray,
        zoom: 9
    });
}
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```